# Не отображается RecyclerView во фрагменте

Tags: android, android-fragment, recyclerview

Есть фрагмент с `RecyclerView`, но почем-то он не отображается. Может быть есть какие-то особенности при работе с адаптером во фрагментах?

```
public class ChooseCurrencyFragment extends Fragment {

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        IFragmentPresenter presenter = ((NewCaptureActivity)getActivity()).getPresenter().getFragmentPresenter();
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_choose_rate, container, false);

        RecyclerView rv = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.rv);
        rv.setHasFixedSize(true);
        LinearLayoutManager llm = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
        rv.setLayoutManager(llm);
        String[] tt = getActivity().getResources().getStringArray(R.array.currencies);
        rv.setAdapter(new CurrencyRecViewAdapter(tt, presenter));
        return view;
    }
}
```

**currency_rec_view_adapter.xml**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/currencyName"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:textSize="30sp" />

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Разметка фрагмента

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

<include layout="@layout/toolbar_search" />

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:paddingTop="8dp"
        android:paddingLeft="16dp"
        android:paddingRight="16dp"
        android:id="@+id/rv" />

</LinearLayout>
```

код вызывающий фрагмент

```
    private void startChooseCurrencyFragment(){
        if (chooseCurrencyFragment == null){
            chooseCurrencyFragment = new ChooseCurrencyFragment();
        }
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.fragment, chooseCurrencyFragment)
              .addToBackStack(chooseCurrencyFragment.getClass().getSimpleName())
                .commit();
    }
```

Код самой активити

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:activity=".View.NewCaptureActivity">

    <SurfaceView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:id="@+id/preview_view"/>

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/fragment"/>

</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: А сам фрагмент-то отображается? Точно?

Comment: покажите код активити, и разметку с ресайклером, возможно у вас просто далеко расположены друг от друга итемы, это раз. Два, возможно вы не правильно вызвали фрагмент. Три, в случае раз - вероятнее всего первый элемент спрятан под тулбаром. Так или иначе - нужно больше информации.

Comment: @post_zeew тулбар отобржается, а фон прозрачный

Answer (score 1):

Нашел косяк, все нормально отображается/работает. Косяк - в адаптере закомичена строка задающая текст айтему, закоммитил и забыл, а черное все потому что где-то задан черный цвет)) Чертова невнимательность))

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте заменить

```
LinearLayoutManager llm = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
```

На:

```
LinearLayoutManager llm = new LinearLayoutManager(getContext());
```

Ну или на:

```
(getActivity().getApplicationContext());
```

Comment: @Vadim_Morozov не помогло((